# Why a template function receives 2D array with 1D reference when a normal function doesn't

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, pass-by-reference

```
void fun (char (&a)[2])  // 1D reference
{}

template<typename T, int SIZE>
void funT (T (&a)[SIZE])  // 1D reference
{}

int main ()
{
  char c[2][2];  // 2D array
  fun(c);  // error
  funT(c); // ok !!!??
}
```

I can expect that `fun()` gives error, but how come `funT()` works fine!
Is there any reference in the standard for such behavior or **Is it a bug** in C++ language?

Comment: In the function template, try printing `cout << sizeof(T) << endl;` .. it will print `2`... which shows that `T` is not `char`, rather something else. Its `char[2]`.

Comment: It is important to note that `char c[2][2]` is not a 2 dimensional array, but rather a one dimensional array of one dimensional arrays. This line of reasoning makes understanding the problem simple. `c` IS a 1D array, just not of `char`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the type of `c` isn't `char [2]`, it doesn't match the first
function.  In the template case, `T` resolves to `char [2]`, which means
that the final argument type is `char (&a)[2][2]`.  (You can think of it
as the `T` becoming the equivalent of a `typedef` to `char[2]`, and
expand the argument type based on that.)

Comment: that was my first guess. I even felt surprised with the pointer related answer from @RedX.

Answer (score 1):

`T` will resolve to <strike>`char*`</strike>`char[2]` and as such there should not be any problems with your templated function.

Edit: Thanks James for pointing that out.

Comment: -1, because the answer is incorrect.  There's no `char*` involved anywhere in his code.